# How to get position in a list using Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have difficulties which you guys might want to help me
my problem

```
......
super(context, R.layout.row_carlo, dataList);
    this.context = context;
    this.urls = dataList;
.......
 holder.textView.setText((Integer) urls.get(position)); <<< error why ?
```

I want to set a text to holder but it gives me an error

EDIT - Error Message:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30953): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
    String resource ID #0x1 11-27 20:09:02.419: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30953): at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:210) 11-27 20:09:02.419: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30953): at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2949)
```

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30953): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30953):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:210)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30953):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2949)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using Integer

try this:

```
Integer i = urls.get(position);
...
setText(Integer.toString(i)); // or String.valueOf(i)
```

`setText(int)` is reserved for resource-IDs like `R.string.xyz`. `Integer` is unboxed to `int` and therefore handled as resource-ID.